# Google Cloud Instance Deletes Files When used with Network Load Balancer

Tags: virtualhost, cloud, storage

I am experimenting with Google Cloud. I was trying to test a VM Instance and Network Load Balancing. Here's what i did:

1. Created an Instance Template => Instance Group => 1 **VM Instance (say VM1)** under the group.
2. **Uploaded all my files on VM1**. Can access all the files using VM1 IP Address.
3. Setup Load Balancing (say LB) on Instance Group.
4. Sent huge traffic to LB and it created another VM Instance (say VM2) to handle the load
5. After the traffic was brought down, LB detected that and decided to delete one VM Instance.
6. Deleted VM1 and now i have only VM2 with no files (originally uploaded to VM1).

Am i getting the whole point of Cloud Computing wrong? How can i keep accessing all the files on the server even when Instances are deleted automatically by LB?